# Compile gmplib on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, compilation, gmp

I try to compile the code of the library for arbitray numeric precision in C(++) at https://gmplib.org/. I want to do this on a Linux system. I use for this the instructions at the page on https://gmplib.org/manual/Installing-GMP.html#Installing-GMP. The problem is that I get the message, that I'm not authorized to do this. I get:
`bash: ./configure: No authorization`
But the only thing I think of are the file access rights. But setting them to maximum rights does not help. Can anyone please tell me, how I can solve the problem?

Comment: You've set access rights, but did you enable rights for execution?

Comment: Yes, I mean all three rights for all three groups. And this in the directory where gmp is saved and all subdirectories and all contained files.

Comment: try running `mount` and see if the the corresponding partition has `noexec` flag or not?

Comment: This solved it. Thank you. So I could build and include the library to an existing project. But now I am no longer able to debug the program by breakpoints. I get messages like the following:Warning:\nCannot insert breakpoint 5.\nCannot access memory at address 0x5555555a0587\n